# Retrieved data is not show on listview

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, android-arrayadapter

here is my code,
    package com.mjzone.project;

```
public class MyDatabase extends Activity {

final protected String DATABASE_TABLE = "details";
private MyDatabaseHelper myHelper;
Context mjContext;
SQLiteDatabase myDb;
String[] values = null;

// ====== Constructor for MyDatabse class ==========

public MyDatabase(Context c) {
    mjContext = c;

}

private class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "MapDatabase", null, 1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                + DATABASE_TABLE
                + " ("
                + BaseColumns._ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR NULL, description VARCHAR NULL,latitude VARCHAR NULL, longitude VARCHAR NULL,image BLOB NULL, category VARCHAR NULL)");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

// ========= to open connection ==============

public MyDatabaseHelper open() throws Exception {
    myHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(mjContext);
    myDb = myHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    return myHelper;

}

// ======== to close connection ===============

public void close() throws Exception{
    myHelper.close();

}

// ========= to create entry ==================

public long createEntry(byte[] iimage, String iname, String idescription,String ilatitude, String ilongitude) {

    ContentValues myBundle = new ContentValues();

    myBundle.put("name", iname);
    myBundle.put("description", idescription);
    myBundle.put("latitude", ilatitude);
    myBundle.put("longitude", ilongitude);
    myBundle.put("image", iimage);
    myBundle.put("category", "NT");

    return myDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, myBundle);

}

// =========== get data ========================

public String[] getData() throws Exception {

    final String[] columns = { BaseColumns._ID, "name", "description","latitude", "longitude", "image", "category" };
    Cursor c = myDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null,null);

    int xname = c.getColumnIndex("name");
    int xdescription = c.getColumnIndex("description");
    int xcategory = c.getColumnIndex("image");

    int i = 0;

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

        values[i] = c.getString(xcategory) + "\t" + c.getString(xname) + "\t" + c.getString(xdescription);
        i++;

    }
            c.close();
    return values;

}
```

}

above is the code of the database class and here is the list demo class

```
public class MyListDemo extends ListActivity{

String[] data; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(arg0);

    try {
        MyDatabase dbObject = new MyDatabase(this);
        dbObject.open();
        data = dbObject.getData();
        MyArrayAdapter adpter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, data);
        setListAdapter(adpter);
        dbObject.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

following shows my Array Adapter class

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private String[] values;
private Context context;

public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
    // Change the icon for Windows and iPhone
    String s = values[position];

    if (s.startsWith("NT")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.camera);
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

this is my layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="22px"
    android:layout_height="22px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    android:layout_marginTop="4px"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="30px" >
</TextView>
```

but list view is not populated for some reason. it shows only the black screen. Could anyone please help me?

thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using SimpleCursorAdapter instead like this: Create a layout with 1 imageView and 2 TextViews(TV1,TV2),let us call it listview_item

```
Cursor c = myDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null,null);

String[] from={"category","name","description"}
int[] to={R.id.IV1,R.id.TV1,R.id.TV2}

SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, listview_item, c, from, to);

adapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {

    public boolean setViewValue(View aView, Cursor aCursor, int aColumnIndex) {
        if(aColumnIndex==aCursor.getColumnIndex("category")){
            String s = aCursor.getString(aCursor.getColumnIndex("category"));

            if (s.startsWith("NT")) {
                ImageView IV= (ImageView) aView;
                IV.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            } else {
                IV.setImageResource(R.drawable.camera);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: i just tried dear, still the same. is my getData() method correct? i wanted to add data to a string array and then retrieve the data via the array adapter. But im not sure if this the correct method

Comment: Once i change it, i get this error log. Then i added the c.close(), but still again it shows the same error,                                             01-12 20:43:36.295: E/Cursor(686): Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/com.mjzone.project/databases/MapDatabase, table = details, query = SELECT _id, name, description, latitude, longitude, image, category FROM details

Comment: Why do i keep getting this error, even after i closed the cursor?    01-12 20:43:36.295: E/Cursor(686): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here

Comment: If you are using sqlite, Why not use a SimpleCursorAdapter() and override setViewBinder?

Comment: Are you sure the DB is created, as it seems from the error you get that the Try statement was not executed. Use the DDMS in Eclipse to open the directory of the App and then look for the DB file and export it to your PC and use sqlite to confirm that the DB and its tables are created correctly.

Comment: im using separate method to add data, but it works fine coz i get a final confirmation dialog at the end.  The reason i didn't use SimpleCursorAdapter() is that i want to generate a logo image as per to the data that is extracted from the database. I couldn't figure out a way to do that using SimpleCursorAdapter().

Comment: Can you suggest me a way to do this using SimpleCursorAdapter()? i could get text through that, but i don't know how set logos for different text with SimpleCursorAdapter(). Im a newbie to Android...

Answer (score 0):

I think your values is null:

```
String[] values = null;

values[i] = c.getString(xcategory) + "\t" + c.getString(xname) + "\t" + c.getString(xdescription);
```

Comment: Thats the same. It should be something like String[] values = new String["number or positions you need in the array"];

Comment: i corrected it. yet i get same errors.. i doubt my getData(). is there any fault in that method?